# how load mysql extensions dockerfile with Docker, Compose with Pfm and Nginx and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I’m new to Docker & Compose. I’ve created a Docker.yml file with nginx, fpm & mysql. docker-compose.yml runs without errors...

I can execute php commands (ie see the results of php commands in browser) but **I can’t execute mysqli** commands. phpinfo.php shows '--enable-mysqlnd’ and it appears to be installed. Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/etc/php is doesn’t have any php.ini… i’m not sure what to do to get this mysql commands to work.

I think I may need to create a Dockerfile for PHP and add mysql extensions after extracting them... but not sure if that's needed....or how to do that correctly -  thanks for the help!

Compose file which runs and brings up 3 Docker contains that I can connect to:

docker-compose.yml

```html
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
            - code-network
        links:
           - php

    php:
        image: php:fpm
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
        networks:
            - code-network
        links:
            - db
    db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
        - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=lbb
      networks:
        - code-network
networks:
    code-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile I've started to work on creating but at the moment doesn't extract code correctly .... not sure if I even need it!

Dockerfile:

```html
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN docker-php-source extract

RUN apt-get update && \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

Comment: OK with much trawling of the Internet - thanks to those nameless heroes! Here is a small Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml that works with MYSQL, NGINX, PFM and mysqli extensions loaded.

Comment: `FROM php:fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev

RUN apt-get install -y php5-memcached
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt mbstring tokenizer mysqli `

Comment: Vin, I was doing exactly what you were doing so I just wanted to say thank you for pointing out this last bit. That was a huge pain!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!